# Chaos Manifested: Can of Worms

Tags: society, magic

In one of the stories I'm working on, I realized I had made a big, *very* big problem. The characters have been infected by Desonia, a manifestation of chaos, and are working as a superpowered response team (Overwatch may be a good example) due to the supernatural abilities they've gained and the fact they have to pay for their treatment *somehow* (Desonia infection, or Dissonance, makes people more likely to gain genetic or mental defects; cancer and insanity would be the chief examples).

What these characters *don't* know is that Desonia is actually solidified essence from an alien being, that contains a fragment of its very soul (AKA life force, essence, being). Why does this matter? Because *Mariposa exists!*
Allow me to explain: if life force from either two members of the same species or two closely related species combines with the material required to create it (an egg cell, in other words), the result is a new organism. This is called Creative Convergence. Unfortunately, Mariposa, the team's foremost medic, has this ability:

a. Overflow-Mariposa regenerates life force every round, and she can grant some or all of that life force to adjacent allies. If her health is full, this health will be given to an ally (or allies) automatically.

In other words, Mariposa has a healing factor comparable to Wolverine's, and since her healing ability utilizes *her own life force,* if she heals a female member of her team, that individual will likely run afoul of Creative Convergence As much as I'd like to leave this uncomplicated, there's a whole lot of factors involved and it looks like I can't do that, so my question is: *What Will Be The Impact Of Mariposa's Overflow Ability on Her Team?*

*Consider:*

1. I'm asking how the team will be impacted when A) any female member that ends up being healed by Mariposa using Overflow ends up pregnant, B) any male that ends up being healed by Overflow ends up hearing voices and feeling strange (see Point 4) and C) this will only happen once for each female individual, for the men to get rid of their 'alternate personality' they'll need to have a child....
2. It's possible since Mariposa is only transferring life energy to others in order to heal them, it will do just that. However, her regeneration and therefore her healing energy is a mix of alien and human lifeforce, and it's extremely likely the two will simply split; human essence will do the actual healing, while the alien essence will seek out and combine with the alien essence already inside the person to be healed. I would judge the latter.
3. I very much doubt that Mariposa's female teammates will appreciate the unexpected effects of her healing (AKA unwanted pregnancy), but at the same time, a Healer who is A) nearly impossible to kill and B) can provide sustained healing to those around her will be *very* hard to replace, seeing as her Overflow ability is unique.
4. Men *are* affected by Mariposa's Overflow as well; the alien lifeforce transferred to them through its healing will combine with the alien lifeforce inside them and create the spirit of a new organism. This spirit won't be able to possess them, but it *will* have access to their memories, thoughts, and emotions, and the "father" will feel the spirit's thoughts and emotions as well.
   Additionally, if they try to have a kid, that child will be that spirit in a child's body. In essence, they'll become the literal father of the mutant that once lived inside them. On the plus side, since Dissonance's negative impact is caused by the alien lifeforce inside Desonia, they no longer will have any potential problems with insanity or cancer!
5. Mariposa isn't the only one who can do this; a vampire-inspired character named Rosanna has an ability named Blood Exchange that can do the same:

b. Blood Exchange-This move only works upon a target in Briar’s Embrace; if the target has more HP than her, that difference is added to her maximum HP. If the target has less HP than her, that difference is added to their maximum HP. Rosanna adds the target’s stats to her own and gains their buffs and protection effects, and vice versa for the target. Additionally, she gains control over the victim. Can only be used once every two months.

Briar's Embrace is an attack that causes briars of shadow to rise up and bind the target in place, an evil vampiric cocoon of sorts.
Looking back, this one is *evil,* as it will impact not only the unfortunate victim but *Rosanna herself.*

Finally, I appreciate your input. Thank you!

Comment: (1) What is *"life force"*? It appears out of nowhere in the second paragraph. (2) What is *"the material required to create life force"?* (3) The third paragraph explains that Madame Butterfly donates *"health"*, not *"life force"*. So, how come the life forces of two beings combine?

Comment: L.Dutch-Reinstate Monica, AlexP, I made my question more specific (it's the impact on Mariposa's _team_) and added information: 1. life force is the energy that gives the body life, manifested by the soul, 2. the material required to create a new organism is an egg cell, and 3. Health is determined by how much life force you have; they're essentially the same thing.

Comment: Set a limit of "being pregnant" to 1, make ever pregnant member take damage in the egg. Or B) make the chaos be stupid and choose nose as the nesting ground (beause it's warm, moist, there are food coming in and out) and be expelled every morning during typical nose cleaning.

Comment: Great suggestion,  SZCZERZO KŁY, but that won't work. The alien essence is connected to the body of its host, it knows where to find the egg cell and it won't damage what's essentially its own. If you have any other ideas, though, I'd be willing to hear them.

Comment: OK, fine. So it comes down to plain old risk of getting pregnant after a casual meeting. This is what pink pills are for. (And I would have thought that female superheroes were on the pill anyway; at least in the movies they don't seem to get pregnant randomly.)

Comment: "Casual meeting?" Mariposa isn't going to heal someone in a 'casual meeting;' think doctor appointment or needed medical attention on the battlefield or during a mission. I'm not sure how birth control works, but I'm pretty sure what is essentially _living chaos_can overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

### New Life Doesn't have to Result in Pregnancy and Whole People:

Rather than this process resulting in a new conception (which would require lots of complex biological things to be perfect and right) look to symbiotes, chimaeras and schizophrenia/MPD for your model. All these things are much more consistent with a chaotic model for you magic system, and result in new life without spawning new independent organisms (unless something dramatic like the character being cut in half happens).

- Symbiotic organisms don't have to have a lot of personality, but could enhance the character by having an independent biological role in the partnership. Maybe they break down toxins, induce endorphin production, or coat the skin and become a kind of armor. They would likely be healing entities, since the donor healer is giving healing essence. Your characters might start healing on their "own" (with the help of the symbiote). Since these are partly the original organism, they may have benevolent intent and synergy. Or, if you want, they can behave selfishly like cancer, trying to take over. Your choice.
- Chimaeras are organisms that contain two often related but distinct genomes. This is most often seen in merged twins (there's even evidence of merged identical twins). So your characters might have new merged genetics (most likely in the tissues that healed) so a character who's eye is gouged out might have the eye grow back a new color, or skin with a different texture, or cancerous. The new flesh might even gradually replace the old, like something out of *The Thing*, but still retain some/all of the original person's identity. Or half the body could simply transform (not sure what your magic system can do).
- Spiritual/lifeforce "new life" might take the form of new mental states. Imagine if the characters start hearing voices of dead people, or aliens, and these beings can be helpful, harmful, or just colorful. A commander starts getting advice from the ghost of Erwin Rommel, while a character who is an ethnic minority is tormented by the ghost of Adolph Hitler, and another is listening to the alien equivalent of talk shows all day.

I'm struggling a little with the internal rules of your system, but I hope this is helpful and gives some insight into alternatives of how engendering new life might be equally as strange/chaotic, but NOT as disruptive to your system.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I didn't provide enough detail. The chimerism is interesting; I can see all sorts of potential in that.

Comment: For example, someone who loses an eye (and their eyes are red) healed by Mariposa would get a duplicate of one of Mariposa's blue eyes, or perhaps a purple eye. The restored material would either be made of Mariposa's cells or exhibit hybridism; I'll probably go with the latter.

Comment: @Alendyias Exactly. For your model, that's how I would see it.

Comment: I'm beginning to see the genius of your suggestion of symbiotic organisms; technically, these new organisms would be born _from_ them, so I can see that being very interesting. I can also see a strange growth sprouting up, causing concern, and then falling off and being dismissed until the resulting organism comes back "home"....hmm....